LateInitilization Error being thrown in Flutter
I am currently trying to compile my code, but each time, I am getting the same LateInitillization error. This looks to be due to my TabController, but I need help here.
I am new to Flutter, but I understand that after the "late," does the InitState not initiate it? Or would I need to initialize the tabController somewhere in the widget?
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 1, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          MySliverAppBar(
            title: MyTabBar(tabController: _tabController),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Divider(
                  indent: 25,
                  endIndent: 25,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                ),
                //Add Current Location from Component
                CurrentLocation(),
                //Add Description from Component
                DescriptionBox(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: 
        TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Item $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Seems ok to me, can you comment other widgets

Try Hot Restart instead of Hot Reloading and see if that works.

Thanks, I'm not sure why I did not try it before, but it's up and running!
